# Увеличить значение и добавить если не существует MySql

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

Помогите составить запрос.
Есть таблица date(date уникальное значение) hour(int) a(int) b(int) c(int) d(int)
Задача: увеличивать значение a-d(одно) для каждого часа каждого дня. Если этой даты и часа в базе нет, создавать строку и увеличивать.

```
INSERT INTO `Stats`(`Date`, `hour`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE, HOUR(CURRENT_TIME), 0, 0, 0, 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `a` = `a` + 1 ,`Date` = CURRENT_DATE, `hour` = HOUR(CURRENT_TIME)
```

Без hour все работает без проблем, каждые сутки создается новая строка. Но в данном примере hour перезаписывается.
Помогите пожалуйста составить запрос что бы увеличивались значения a-d с уникальной датой и по часам.
Спасибо.

Comment: а индекс кто будет уникальный делать? Пушкин А.С.?

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем он тут? Буду признателен если поделитесь правильным примером. ЗЫ я в мускуле вообще 0, вдруг понадобилось собирать статистику и вот я здесь:)

Comment: Зачем? Это вот сейчас прям вот серьёзно? Ну тогда надо садиться и почитать про  то как работает ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Ну и заодно перечитать первую строчку своего же вопроса, где говорится про поле date

Comment: Забабахать не date и time 2 столбцами, а datetime одним, не? Уникальным. И если тебе нужно потом вынуть данные за дату, делаешь не `where date = %need_date%`, а `where date LIKE %need_date%`

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 вам тоже не помешает почитать про то, как работает ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. чтобы не писать ерунды